# locked myself out of Magento 2.2.5 /admin

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

In the process of trying to learn Magento I reset the cookie domain in  System > Configuration > General > Web  according to this article:

https://www.sitepoint.com/fix-magento-login-issues-cookies-sessions/

It appears I entered a bad value (.www.domainname.com) and can now not get into the admin panel.  I am trying to support a client who has a Magento staging site on an AWS Bitnami Lightsail instance.  But the client seems to have locked down PHPMYADMIN and remote connections to the MySQL database.

SO, is there any way to reset the cookie domain for this staging site WITHOUT access to the database?

Comment: Ok I got access to the MYSQL database.  So I can try to reset the cookie domain with a SQL command.  Now back to my original issue:  Magento 2.2.5 My Account button does not work.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can set configuration via bin magento

`bin/magento config:set [configpath] [value]`

Without the buckets.

More info in dev docs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-set.html